# where does the modulus go when cancelling $e$ and $\ln$ in this problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponentiation

So I did this problem today:

> Show that $\frac{dy}{dx} = yx^2$ can be written as $y = Ae^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$

my solution is shown below:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = yx^2
$$
$$
\frac{1}{y} dy = x^2 dx
$$
$$
\int\frac{1}{y}\ dy = \int x^2\ dx
$$
$$
\ln |y| = \frac{x^3}{3} + C
$$
$$
e^{\ln |y|} = e^{\frac{x^3}{3} + C}
$$
$$
y = e^{\frac{x^3}{3} + C}
$$
$$
y = Ae^{\frac{x^3}{3}}
$$

But I don't understand what happens to the modulus around the $y$? Why isn't it $|y| = Ae^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$? What happens if the modulus is in fact left there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $e^x\ge 0\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ so the modulus sign is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remember, that $e^c$ respectively A is always positiv. So the whole Expression on the right hand is positiv: |y|=y

greetings,

calculus .

Comment: That helps, because I was mostly confused not acknowledging that A > 0.